# Select from certain character till certain character only if condition is met mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with a problem, I am a beginner in mysql and I was assigned to create a query that extracts values from url addresses. So basically I have thousands of url addresses like this for example https://www.google.com/search?source= where I need to extract everything from the last '/' till the first '?'(in this case 'search'). And it's not that simple, sometimes it's http, sometimes the number of '/' characters is not the same and sometimes is a faulty address(i need to ignore those cases) and sometimes I have a case where I have a regular https://google.com/search and no '?'(these cases need to be ignored as well. I am up to here but I feel helpless, any suggestions?

```
select distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'/',0) col from table where length(col) - length(replace(col, '/', '')) >= 1 
         and length(col) - length(replace(col, '?', '')) >= 1 
                and col = 'value'
                    and col <> ''
                      and col is not null 
                        order by date
                         limit 600;
```

Comment: provide samples of the data, both valid and invalid, then manually prepare and provide the "expected result" you want from that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for the question mark first. Then if that exists use a substring to that position, reversed, to locate the "slash prior to the ?", and then I can extract that portion of the url once I know where the / is and the ? is:

```
select
  url
, substr(url,1,qmarkpos-1)
, case when qmarkpos > 0 then instr(reverse(substr(url,1,qmarkpos-1)),'/') end
, substr(substr(url,1,qmarkpos-1),qmarkpos-instr(reverse(substr(url,1,qmarkpos-1)),'/'),qmarkpos)
from (
        select url, instr(url,'?') qmarkpos
        from (
             select 'https://www.google.com/search?source=' as url union all
             select 'https://www.google.com/search' as url union all
             select 'https://www.google.com/search?source=uqu iqu iugqidug iqugd' as url union all
             select 'https://www.google.com/search?source/qh ohqod hi=' as url            
            ) d
     ) d2

+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
|   |                             url                             |   substr(url,1,qmarkpos-1)    | case ... end | result  |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1 | https://www.google.com/search?source=                       | https://www.google.com/search | 7            | /search |
| 2 | https://www.google.com/search                               |                               | NULL         |         |
| 3 | https://www.google.com/search?source=uqu iqu iugqidug iqugd | https://www.google.com/search | 7            | /search |
| 4 | https://www.google.com/search?source/qh ohqod hi=           | https://www.google.com/search | 7            | /search |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HFD7164)

Comment: Sorry to rephrase, from 'https://www.google.com/search?source='  i need to extract www.google.com i.e remove everything from the start till the end of :// including :// till the ? or if the ? is not present everything from www.google.com/ up till 250 characters.   @Used_By_Already

Comment: Not sure what that comment is for.